# Docker windows authentication for .NET core API -httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name returning null

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

Docker windows authentication for .NET core API -httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name returning null , Can anyone please help?

[image]

Comment: Are you running your app with IISExpress in vs?

Comment: @C1sc0   running .net core api with docker

Comment: So your code is working in visual studio?

Comment: @C1sc0 yes in vs code, issue is with docker only